# Magento2 - Override Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

Tags: magento2, overrides, knockoutjs

How can we override  `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` file?

I need to add some custom code to `selectShippingMethod` function so i can hide/show a block if a specific shipping method is selected.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just found a way to override that function using 'mixins'.

> On requirejs-config.js file I had to add:

```js
var config = {
      config: {
                mixins: {
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                        'Mynamespace_Mymodule/js/view/shipping': true
                    }
                }
       }
}
```

> Create a file
> Mynamespace/Mymodule/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
        'uiRegistry',
        'mage/translate',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
    ],function (
        $,
        _,
        Component,
        ko,
        customer,
        addressList,
        addressConverter,
        quote,
        createShippingAddress,
        selectShippingAddress,
        shippingRatesValidator,
        formPopUpState,
        shippingService,
        selectShippingMethodAction,
        rateRegistry,
        setShippingInformationAction,
        stepNavigator,
        modal,
        checkoutDataResolver,
        checkoutData,
        registry,
        $t) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
            console.log("method overriden");
            selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod.carrier_code + '_' + shippingMethod.method_code);

            return true;
        }
    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../default returns.
    return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive 
};
});
```

Helpful info:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1864
[Magento2 - Override Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128292/magento2-override-magento-checkout-view-frontend-web-js-view-shipping-js)

Comment: frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Namespace_Module/js/view/shipping.js 404 (Not Found)
req.load @ require.js:1895
load @ require.js:1639
load @ require.js:820
fetch @ require.js:810
check @ require.js:840
enable @ require.js:1143
enable @ require.js:1511
(anonymous) @ require.js:1128
(anonymous) @ require.js:132
each @ require.js:57
enable @ require.js:1090
init @ require.js:774
(anonymous) @ require.js:1416

Comment: You only need to define the sources you're using, not every single one shipping is using.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case the requirejs-config.js file should look like this:

```
var config = {
     config:
       {
         mixins:
           {'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping':
               {'Namespace_Module/js/view/shipping': true }
           }
       }
   };
```

This worked for me

Comment: can you please help me Sir with this scenario??? I used your `requirejs-config.js` file and I copied all the code of `shipping.js` file but on checkout page it returns me blank page... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293270/how-to-disable-province-zipcode-and-country-from-checkout-magento-2-2?noredirect=1#comment421503_293270

Answer (score 3):

You can override core module **js** by using custom theme.

You have to copy js file from

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

and put it given path

```
/app/design/frontend/Theme/Packadge/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-information.js
```

modify by your changes in the file.

Run below command for deploy static content

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now check your changes and let me know if you have any query.