# magento 2 knockout js / require js subscribe to another files parameter

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

What I need to do is subscribe to another file / object via knockout js and require js.

For example I have in File1.js:

```
define(
[
    '/path/to/some/component',
    'ko'
],
function (Component, ko) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({

        // this is the var that I need to subscribe to in File2
        somevar: ko.observable(null);

        // I have an event that triggers this method in another 
        // external file that sets somevar
        myEvent: function(value){
           somevar(value);
        }
   });
});
```

and in file2.js I need to do something like

```
define(
[
    '/path/to/some/component',
    '/path/to/file#1',
    'ko'
],
function (Component, File1, ko) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({

        // set a new observable var in file 2
        subscribeVar: ko.observable(null);

        initialize : function(){

            // and subscribe to the change in value of the var in 
            // file 1
            File1.somevar() .subscribe(function(anotherValue){
                // here I want to execute my logic but the    
                // illustrated method of doing this is not working.
            }, this);
        },
   });
});
```

Comment: I had the same issue, it helped me: [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128292/magento2-override-magento-checkout-view-frontend-web-js-view-shipping-js)

Answer (score 0):

I used this construction to call other uiComponent

```
define([
    ...
    'uiRegistry',
], function (..., registry) {
    'use strict';

    ...
        let callback = function (component) {
            component.anyFuncFromAnotherComponent;
        };
        registry.get('ComponentName', callback);
```